# fit size of parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a simple linear layout and want to divide the screen into two equally sized parts.

In the upper one, I want to put a `SurfaceView` that has exactly the same size as its parent, i.e. half of the screen. Unfortunately, it always either takes all the screen or nothing (depending on the configuration).
Why is that and how can I change it?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutUpperDaw"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#192832">

        <com.example.MySurvfaceView
            android:id="@+id/id_mySurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="0pt"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            OR

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            >

        </com.example.MySurvfaceView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#193222">

        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide `weight` you have to set height or weight to 0dp as below.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutUpperDaw"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#192832">
```

and

```
<com.example.MySurvfaceView
            android:id="@+id/id_mySurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
```

**Update**: Answer above is correct about weight usage, make sure either hight or width is 0dp at all places where you used weight.

You don't really need nested LinearLayout. Following should work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.example.MySurvfaceView
            android:id="@+id/id_mySurfaceView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >

        </com.example.MySurvfaceView>



    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#193222">


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does not work for me. The `MySurfaceView` is not visible then.

Comment: Ok, the approach without the first nested inner `LinearLayout` works, but I'm not sure I got the logic behind the LinearLayout. When I add  a `LinearLayout` with `weight=1` and `height=0` around `MySurvfaceView` it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically:

1. Find the parent layout.

   GridLayout gridLayout =(GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);`
2. Get measured height and Width of parent.

   int height = gridLayout.measuredHeight();

   int width = gridLayout.measuredWidth();

3.Calculate child view height and width.For example two child each taking 50% of height in the parent but taking full width of parent:

```
int childHeight = height/2;
int childWidth = width;
```

4.Get instanceof LayoutParams depending on parent type.

```
GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
```

5. Set height and width on layout params.

```
 params.width = childWidth;
 params.height = childHeight;
```

6.Create child view and set Layout params.

```
ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
imageview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

7.Add child View to parent.

```
 gridLayout.addView(ImageView);
```